# ACF relationship fields 'The results could not be loaded'

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Would anyone know why the ACF relationship field is not showing results in the backend. This affects any type of relationship field - the entry list pane is just empty?

Comment: Are there JS errors in the console?

Comment: No, but it was comments in functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was comments in functions.php. Probably school boy error, but if anyone can explain, would be interested to hear.

Comment: It would be hard to explain without seeing any of the code. :)

Comment: It was just this at the top of functions.php <!-- -->

Comment: Functions.php holds functions to be run on hooks. If you accidentally place code like an HTML comment `<!-- -->` or even too many line breaks, that may be executed at a time when WordPress isn't ready to start outputting content, and break all sorts of things.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution! Make sure you call

`wp_footer();`

in this file:

`wp-content\themes\twentytwenty\footer.php`